# calling grandparent method from grandchild functional component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to call a simple method from the grandparent component in my child component but from some reason I can't  ,  I tried every possible way but I think I'm missing something
here's the full code :

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

var todos = [
  {
    title: "Example2",
    completed: true
  }
]
const TodoItem = (props) => {
  return (
    <li 
    className={props.completed ? "completed" : "uncompleted"}
    key={props.index} onClick={props.handleChangeStatus}
    >
    
    {props.title}
    </li>
  );
}
class TodoList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    

  }
  render () {
    return (
    <ul>
      {this.props.todosItems.map((item , index) => (
        <TodoItem  key={index} {...item} {...this.props} handleChangeStatus={this.props.handleChangeStatus}  />
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
  }
  
}

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      todos ,
      text :""
    }
    this.handleTextChange = this.handleTextChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeStatus = this.handleChangeStatus(this);

  }
  handleTextChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      text: e.target.value
    });
  }
  handleChangeStatus(){
    console.log("hello");
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newItem = {
      title : this.state.text , 
      completed : false
    }
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      todos : prevState.todos.concat(newItem),
      text : ""
    }))
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Todos </h1>
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
            < input type="text" onChange={this.handleTextChange} value={this.state.text}/>
          </form>
          
        </div>
        <div>
          <TodoList handleChangeStatus={this.handleChangeStatus} todosItems={this.state.todos} />
        </div>
        <button type="button">asdsadas</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The method im trying to use is handleChangeStatus() from the App component in the TodoItem component

Thank you all for your help

Comment: the snippet is broke

Comment: Found it: look at the `constructor` for `App`; you're calling the function instead of `bind`ing it. You can get rid of those `bind` calls if you define your class functions as `handleSubmit = (e) => {...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
this.handleChangeStatus = this.handleChangeStatus(this);

//Change to this and it works

this.handleChangeStatus = this.handleChangeStatus.bind(this);
```